# Random complex eigenvalues and averages of traces

Tags: pr.probability, random-matrices

I have asked this in MSE [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2854782/random-complex-eigenvalues-and-averages-of-traces), but got no interesting answers.

Suppose I have a random matrix $M$ of dimension $N$ which is real, but not symmetric. Suppose I know that, for large $N$, the marginal distribution of its eigenvalues is uniform over the unit disk in the complex plane. What does that tell me about the average values of traces, $\langle {\rm Tr}(M^n)\rangle$?

Of course $\langle {\rm Tr}(M^n)\rangle \to 0$ as $N\to\infty$, but can I know the asymptotics?

Does it follow from the "disk law" for the eigenvalues that the singular values have a quarter-circle distribution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Summary: I don't think the average $\langle {\rm Tr}(M^n)\rangle \to 0$ for $N\rightarrow\infty$, at least for $n$ even I will argue this average is $\propto\sqrt N$ because of the contributions from eigenvalues on the real axis.

---

• Consider first the eigenvalues $\lambda_p=r_p e^{i\phi_p}$ of $M$ off the real axis. Because $M$ is real these must come in complex conjugate pairs, $\lambda_p=\lambda^\ast_{N-p}$, so 
$${\rm Tr}\, M^n=2\sum_{p=1}^{N/2} r_p^n \cos n\phi_p,$$
and the average 
$$\langle{\rm Tr}\,M^n\rangle_{\rm complex}=N\int_0^\infty dr \int_0^{2\pi}d\phi\, P(r,\phi)\, r^{n+1} \cos n\phi.$$
Under the assumption that the eigenvalue density $P(r,\phi)$ in the complex plane is rotationally invariant in the unit disc this average is zero.

• Now turn to the eigenvalues on the real axis. There are $N_{\rm real}=c\sqrt N$ real eigenvalues for $N\gg 1$, where the coefficient $c$ depends on the distribution of $M$. (For a Gaussian $M$ one has $c=\sqrt{2/\pi}$.) The real eigenvalues are uniformly distributed in the interval $(-1,1)$. So their contribution to the average is
$$\langle {\rm Tr}\,M^n\rangle_{\rm real}=c\sqrt{N}\int_{-1}^{1} r^n dr=\begin{cases}
\frac{2c}{n+1}\sqrt{N}&\text{if n is even},\\
0&\text{if n is odd}.
\end{cases}$$

It is likely that the deviations from uniformity in the distribution of complex eigenvalues also give a nonzero contribution of the same order $\sqrt N$ as those from the real axis. (Basically because the eigenvalues that are pinned to the real axis repel nearby eigenvalues with nonzero imaginary part, see plot below.)

---

[image]
[image]

Illustration of the eigenvalue distribution in the complex plane for three different ensembles of real random matrices (of size $N=100$). You can see the eigenvalues pinned to the real axis (they appear as a horizontal black line of dense points), surrounded by a depletion zone (white region of few points). The ensemble of Hamiltonian matrices has an additional symmetry that also pins eigenvalues to the imaginary axis. In each case the number $N_X$ of real eigenvalues scales as $\sqrt N$, with a different numerical prefactor (red line for Hamiltonian ensemble, blue for skew-GOE, Ginibre has $\sqrt{2N/\pi}$).
Figures from [arxiv:1305.2924.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1305.2924)

Comment: In the last part of your answer, you are actually assuming that the distribution of eigenvalues is *not* uniform over the disc, right? I know that is the case for real Ginibre ensemble, so I guess you are assuming that this is universal...

Comment: indeed, the $\sqrt N$ law is generic, I added a plot and a reference to illustrate this; for a uniform distribution you will need complex matrices, rather than real matrices.

Comment: Dear Carlo, are you aware of published results for the traces of powers for real Ginibre?

Comment: Another point. The sum over *complex* eigenvalues $\sum_\lambda \lambda^n$ could in principle also be of order $\sqrt{N}$, right?

Comment: yes, all eigenvalues within the unit circle that lie in  a strip of width $1/\sqrt N$ around the real axis will contribute order $\sqrt N$ to the sum.

Comment: I have found a surprisingly simple expression for traces of powers of matrices from the real Ginibre ensemble in this paper by Sommers and Khoruzhenko: https://arxiv.org/pdf/0903.5071.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Carlo's answer addresses the first question. To address the second one: the "disk law" (better known as the "circular law") does not tell you the distribution of singular values.  However, the Marchenko-Pastur law does, and it is true that the singular values have a quarter-circle distribution, but with a different normalization than the circular law would lead you to expect.

Answer (score 2):

The following only addresses the last question on the relation between eigenvalues and singular values.

What the eigenvalue distribution does not tell you, are traces in products of $M$ and $M^*$; since the singular values are given by the distribution of $MM^*$, the eigenvalue distribution does not contain enough information to conclude from this on the singular values. For example, you can compare the limit of the Ginibre ensemble and a normal random matrix ensemble (i.e., one with $MM^*=M^*M$) which has asymptotically a uniform distribution on the disk. So both ensembles have the disk law for the eigenvalue distribution, but in the first case the singular values have the quarter-circular distribution, whereas in the second case one gets, I think, a linear density for the singular values.